# Creating a Socket IO channels from client side

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm new to Nodejs and Socketio. I want to do something like the following.

-> Create a socket.io/node.js server that listens to channels specified by the web browser.
-> server side script pushes messeges to specific channels.

(I already have a server created and here is the code. This just sends out two messeges. action and messege to all the connected clients)

```
//start code    
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , url = require('url')

app.listen(8080);

function handler (req, res) {
    // parse URL
    var requestURL = url.parse(req.url, true);

    // if there is a message, send it
    if(requestURL.query.message)
            sendMessage(decodeURI(requestURL.query.action), decodeURI(requestURL.query.message));

    // end the response
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end("");
}

function sendMessage(action, message) {
    io.sockets.emit('notification', {'action': action, 'message' : message});
}
```

So basically Socket.io server doesn't have any channels defined inside them. But they are defined by the client (js in browser) and messeges are sent to the specific channels by a server side script (like php using cURL)

Sorry if this questions has been asked before, I did search and couldnt find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I am bit confused about your question. By channels, do you mean socket.io rooms?
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms

Rooms are groups of clients and it is possible to send message to all clients in room by using following command:

```
io.sockets.in('room').emit('event_name', data)
```

It is important to realize that rooms are server side thing. So, if you want to send message to a room from client, you must send message (or request) to server and pass room name.

Also, it is bit unusual that your handler function is exposed as HTTP endpoint. If your clients already have socket.io connections, than it is easier to send it as socket.io message.

If this does not answer you question, can you post also your client side code? Maybe it will help to understand me what are you trying to achieve.